# How to fetch the associated Lead Records for an account entity in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

How to fetch the associated Lead Records for an account entity in MS Dynamics CRM.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (collection != null && collection.Entities != null && collection.Entities.Count > 0)
            {
                /*Add method call here/
                contacts = collection.Entities.ToList();
            }
```

In this condition you can add call of new method that will collect for you associated lead records.
You have `collection.Entities`. Loop it like `foreach(var Entity in collection.Entities)`. From there you can get `Id` that you need or you will get information that you need.

Comment: He asking not how `to fetch` but how to fetch `for account` entity.